# Does Android support AES256/CTR/NoPadding?

Tags: android, security, encryption

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES256/CTR/NoPadding")
```

The above code throws the following exception:

> Stack trace: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException:
>   AES256/CTR/NoPadding   at
>   javax.crypto.Cipher.getCipher(Cipher.java:296)   at
>   javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:174)

Does Android support "AES256/CTR/NoPadding"?  Is this device dependent?  The Android device I am testing has the following providers:

- AndroidOpenSSL version 1.0
- DRLCertFactory version 1.0
- BC version 1.47
- Crypto version 1.0
- HarmonyJSSE version 1.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **Cipher.java** You can see available transformations. Unfortunatelly there isn't "AES256/CTR/NoPadding" (and thats why you see this exception) but there is of course "AES/CTR/NoPadding" and you should use it.

The AES keysize (as used within Cipher) fully depends on the key in Android, so You should just generate and use key of appropriate length.

In Api level 26+ you can use directly "AES_256..." but only for CBC and ECB modes (https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html)

Comment: "In Cipher.java..." Where is Cipher.java?

Comment: Thank you.  I have tried Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding") with a 256-bit key, and it appears to work.  It will take me a little bit time to confirm it.

Comment: @Hong Is that for 26+ only?

Comment: @TheRealChx101 No. minSdkVersion = 16.

Comment: Hey @Hong, do you have an example of using AES/CTR/NoPadding with a 256-bit key? I am struggling to find a well-documented example with this concrete case.

Comment: @SergioGutiérrez It is difficult to add code in comments.  You could post a question to allow me to answer it with code.